# How to get the button id into model in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have two button  namely next and submit. When i click the next button some validation will work.And when click submit button both next and submit button validation will work.how can i do.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('place', 'required', 'message' => 'Please select Working At'),
        array('empno', 'required', 'message' => 'Please fill Employee No'),
     );
}
```

Comment: these rules look ok... what's the purpose of your 'next' button? if you would paste the form view it would be easier to help...

Comment: next button click its goes to the remaining form fields.

Comment: does it call an ajax / javascript function that loads the remaining form fields? pls add the contents of your js function and your form to your post (click edit)...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the following buttons:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="action" VALUE=" next">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="action" VALUE=" submit">
```

Then in your controller you could do

```
$model = new Model;
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    if($_POST['action'] == "next") {
        $model->scenario = "next"
    } else {
        $model->scenario = "submit"
    }
}
//Assign the attributes
$model->validate();//or save or anything you want to do
```

And in the rules of you model you can set some rules that apply only on the submit scenario (first example) or to all scenario except the next one (second example)

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('place', 'required', 'message' => 'Please select Working At', 'on' => 'submit'),
        array('empno', 'required', 'message' => 'Please fill Employee No', 'except' => 'next'),
     );
}
```

Comment: My next and create buttons are,<?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Next' : 'Next', array('class'=>'btn btn-bricky','id'=>"btnReview")); ?><?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', array('class'=>'btn btn-bricky')); ?>

Comment: Try to add the name and the value of the submit CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Next' : 'Next', array('class'=>'btn btn-bricky','id'=>"btnReview", 'name' => 'action', 'value'=> $model->isNewRecord ? 'Next' : 'submit' ));

Comment: Where to define the next button and submit button validation

Comment: you check in the controller wich button has been clicked, and the validation rules are in your model. All of this is pretty standard, you should check the yii guide

Comment: Please give reference url

Comment: I tried this code is woking for meif($model->validate(array('a','b')))
{
    if($model->validate(array('c')))
    {
        $model->save()
    }
}